# Setting a List indexed property with BeanUtils

Tags: java, javabeans, apache-commons-beanutils

I'm attempting to use BeanUtils to interact with a Java bean similar to the following:

```
public class Bean {
    private List<Integer> prices = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public List<Integer> getPrices() {
        return prices;
    }
}
```

According to the [BeanUtils documentation](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#standard), BeanUtils does support indexed properties that are `List`s:

> As an extension to the JavaBeans specification, the BeanUtils package considers any property whose underlying data type is java.util.List (or an implementation of List) to be indexed as well.

However, let's say I try to do something like the following:

```
Bean bean = new Bean();

// Add nulls to make the list the correct size
bean.getPrices().add(null);
bean.getPrices().add(null);

BeanUtils.setProperty(bean, "prices[0]", 123);
PropertyUtils.setProperty(bean, "prices[1]", 456);

System.out.println("prices[0] = " + BeanUtils.getProperty(bean, "prices[0]"));
System.out.println("prices[1] = " + BeanUtils.getProperty(bean, "prices[1]"));
```

The output is:

```
prices[0] = null
prices[1] = 456
```

Why is `BeanUtils.setProperty()` unable to set the indexed property, while `PropertyUtils.setProperty()` can?  Does BeanUtils not support type conversion for objects inside `List`s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BeanUtils` requires a setter method for it to work. Your `Bean` class is missing the setter method for `prices`, add this and rerun your code, it should work fine:-

```
public void setPrices(List<Integer> prices) {
    this.prices = prices;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does make it work.  However, stepping through the actual BeanUtils source, I noticed that it doesn't actually use the setPrices() method to modify the contents of the prices List - it just uses the getPrices() method and modifies the list directly.